# How to determine the number of bins and the edge length based on the density of each bin. (Bins most likely are not uniform.)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, histogram, bin

I have been trying to figure out how to write a function to bin a sample of data together based on its density (Number of Occurrence/ Length of edge). But there are not alot of examples out there.

The output would give a vector of edges where both :

1. the number of bins are given by how many are required to group data that have different density by a threshold (maybe 40%?)
2. and the length of the edges are determined by if the adjacent data groups have similar density. (Similar density are grouped together, but if the neighboring bin is 40% more or less in density, it would require another bin).

So to illustrate my point, below is a simple example:

I have data values that ranges from 1 to 10 and I have 10 observations of it where x=[1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6, 6,7];

x would result in a range with edges that are [1,5,6,7,8], so there are four states just because the bins represent different density clusters.

Just to mention my actual data is continuous, any help is appreciated.

I thought of a preliminary algorithm for large data samples:

1. Sort data in ascending order.
2. Group data where at least a group has 10 elements
3. Calculate and compare density to group similar ones together.

I got stuck on the 3rd point. Where I am not sure how to effectively group them. My obstacle comes from if the density increases slowly, but gradually e.g. Density: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Where do I call it break and say that one group has a different density from another.

Comment: I am trying write the above in matlab code. thanks

Comment: Sounds like a clustering problem. Maybe you can use k-means clustering and then use something like silhouette plots to choose k?